# Extract Log Entries of the Current Date

Tags: perl

I have log entries in the following format:

```
[29-Oct-2014 06:06:08] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 104151
[29-Oct-2014 06:06:26] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[29-Oct-2014 06:07:14] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[29-Oct-2014 06:07:14] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Oct-2014 06:07:16] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 104871
[31-Oct-2014 06:07:36] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Oct-2014 06:41:48] WARNING: [pool blah.com] child 105502 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: "
[31-Oct-2014 06:41:48] WARNING: [pool blah.com] child 105502 said into stderr: ""
```

I simply want to print the entries that are of the current date (31-Oct).

I have been playing with the following script but I can't get it to work:

```
use strict;
use Logwatch ':dates';
use Time::Local;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date_format = '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S';
my $filter = TimeFilter($date_format);

# we do not use any Date:: package (or strptime) as they are probably not available
my %month2num = ( Jan => 0, Feb => 1, Mar => 2, Apr => 3,
                  May => 4, Jun => 5, Jul => 6, Aug => 7,
                  Sep => 8, Oct => 9, Nov => 10, Dec => 11 );

# counting messages
while(<>) {
    my $line = $_;
    # skipping messages that are not within the requested range
    next unless $line =~ /^\[($filter)\]/o;
    $1 =~ /(\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/;
    my $time;

    {
        # timelocal is quite chatty
        local $SIG{'__WARN__'}  = sub {};
        $time = timelocal($6, $5, $4, $1, $month2num{$2}, $3-1900);
    }

}
```

I'm unable to extract the date in a format that I can compare with and I'm not sure how to compare to the current date.

Comment: Is [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) present?

Comment: or [Time::ParseDate](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Time-modules-2003.0211/lib/Time/ParseDate.pm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do something more complicated with the dates, the filter, or the log entries you extract? Working with dates and ranges can be tricky but you just seem to be looking for a specific date string (i.e. "the current date").

```
perl -MTime::Piece -nE'$t=localtime; $tdate=$t->mday."-".$t->monname."-".$t->year;
 say if m/^\[$tdate/' logs.txt
```

**Output:**

```
[31-Oct-2014 06:07:16] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 104871
[31-Oct-2014 06:07:36] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Oct-2014 06:41:48] WARNING: [pool blah.com] child 105502 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: "
[31-Oct-2014 06:41:48] WARNING: [pool blah.com] child 105502 said into stderr: ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code in perl:

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;   

sub Dt_change
{
    my $date_var=$_[0];
    my $temp;
    my %Month=(1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Feb', 3 => 'Mar', 4 => 'Apr' , 5 => 'May' ,6 => 'Jun' , 7 => 'Jul', 8 => 'Aug' ,9 => 'Sep', 10 => 'Oct', 11 => 'Nov' , 12 => 'Dec');
    if($date_var=~/^(\d+)\/0?(\d+)\/(\d+)$/)
      {
        my $day=$1;
        my $year=$3;
        my $month=$2;           
        $temp="$day" . "\-" . "$Month{$month}" . "\-" . "$year"; 
        }
      return $temp      
     } 

my $logFile = $ARGV[0];    
open my $fh,'<',$logFile or die "Couldn't open the log file $logFile:$!";          
my $t = localtime;
my $date = $t -> dmy("/");
my $dateformat = "\[" . Dt_change($date);
my $fulldateformat = "\[" . Dt_change($date) . " " . $t -> hms . "\]"; 
$dateformat = quotemeta($dateformat);
print "Current date log entries:\n";
while(<$fh>)
 {
    if($_ =~ /$dateformat/is)
      { 
         print "line number $. -> $_\n";
        }
    }   
close($fh);
```

**Usage:**

```
perl filename.pl logfile
```